# Multiple active items in menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using sb-admin2 (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) and django, and the menu is showing multiple active options (as shown in the picture below):

Here is what it looks like when I select the first option (Name). This is correct since i am inside add and have selected Name.

[image]

Here is what it looks like when I select the second element.  This is wrong since the first and second option both are active.  Only Add and Age should be active.

[image]

This is only happening for this particular dropdown in the menu, not any other.  All the other dropdowns in the menu have the exact same code the only differing thing is the href url.  I tried ordering the dropdowns around but it still only happends to the Add dropdown.

Here is the html code for this portion:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
   <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    ...
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>
            Add
            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-second level">
            <li>
              <a href="{% url "nameFirst" %}">First Names</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{% url "nameLast" %}">Last Names</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="{% url "occupation" %}">Occupations</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
 ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The relevant url section in urls.py:

```
...
  url(r"^nameFirst$", NameFirstView.as_view(), name="nameFirst"),
  url(r"^nameLast$", NameLastView.as_view(), name="nameLast"),
...
```

The pages go to the correct destination, and the menu functions properly.  The only thing is that it is showing the wrong active option as shown in the pictures.

EDIT:

I added the following code to the bottom:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("a").click(function(){
        $("a").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active")
      })
    })                                                   
  </script>
```

This still did not fix the problem.

I also edited the question to show that I am using django since it seems that it might have to do with django.  The problem is only occurring only for this dropdown in the menu not any other.

Comment: I check and try to reproduce the problem but it seems menu active class is working properly you have to share the site link,

Comment: I don't have an online version of the site, is there any other file or code portion you would like to see?